# Idea plugins JavaRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression not invoked

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, plugins

I write my visitor implementation and pass it to action.
When I call that action, I see a lot of "VISITED Psi... with class ..." lines,
including "VISITED PsiMethodCallExpression:commentRepository.delete(comment) with class class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiMethodCallExpressionImpl" that I want to found, but method visitMethodCallExpression is not called - not a single one "methodCall visited",
similarly for visitForeachStatement.

Why is the method visitMethodCallExpression not being called and how to fix this?

code:

```
package mypackage

import com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement
import com.intellij.psi.PsiForStatement
import com.intellij.psi.PsiForeachStatement
import com.intellij.psi.PsiMethodCallExpression

class AnalyzeVisitor: JavaRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor() {
    private var forVisited: Boolean = false

    override fun visitElement(element: PsiElement) {
        println("VISITED $element with class ${element::class.java}")
        super.visitElement(element)
    }

    override fun visitForStatement(statement: PsiForStatement) {
        forVisited = true
        println("forStatement visited '$statement'")
        super.visitForStatement(statement)
    }

    override fun visitForeachStatement(statement: PsiForeachStatement?) {
        forVisited = true
        println("foreachStatement visited'$statement'")
        super.visitForeachStatement(statement)
    }

    override fun visitMethodCallExpression(expression: PsiMethodCallExpression) {
        println("methodCall visited '$expression'")
        if (forVisited) {
            println("visited")
            // some logic
        }
        super.visitMethodCallExpression(expression)
    }
}
```

code on that I call visitor

```
package another.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.itmo.wp.domain.Comment;
import ru.itmo.wp.repository.CommentRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CommentService {
    private final CommentRepository commentRepository;

    public CommentService(CommentRepository commentRepository) {
        this.commentRepository = commentRepository;
    }

    public void saveComment(Comment comment) {
        commentRepository.save(comment);
    }

    public boolean deleteCommentAndDoLogic(Comment comment) {
        commentRepository.delete(comment);
        System.out.println("Comment deleted " + comment.getText());
        return true;
    }

    public void deleteCommentsSimple(List<Comment> comments) {
        for (Comment comment: comments) {
            commentRepository.delete(comment);
        }
    }

    public void deleteCommentsInner(List<Comment> comments) {
        for (Comment comment: comments) {
            boolean t = deleteCommentAndDoLogic(comment);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change visitElement method to

```
    override fun visitElement(element: PsiElement) {
        println("VISITED $element with class ${element::class.java}")
        when(element) {
            is PsiMethodCallExpression -> {
                visitMethodCallExpression(element)
            }
            is PsiForStatement -> {
                visitForStatement(element)
            }
            is PsiForeachStatement -> {
                println("FOUND FOREACH")
                visitForeachStatement(element)
            }
        }
        if (element is PsiMethodCallExpression) {
            visitMethodCallExpression(element)
        }
        super.visitElement(element)
    }
```

But it won't help, because PsiMethodCallExpression is LeafPsiElement